# Javascript: Re-assigning a function with another function

Tags: javascript, function, closures, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
function fnChanger(fn) {
    fn = function() { sys.print('Changed!'); }
}
function foo() {
    sys.print('Unchanged');
}
```

Now, if I call `foo()`, I see `Unchanged`, as expected. However, if I call `fnChanger` first, I still see `Unchanged`:

```
fnChanger(foo);
foo(); //Unchanged
```

Now, I assume this is because `foo` is not being passed to `fnChanger` by reference, but I may be wrong.

Why does `fnChanger` not change `foo` to print `Changed!`?
Furthermore, how can I get `fnChanger` to change `foo` without too much messy syntax?

PS: I'm using node.js to test all this stuff, so that's where the `sys.print` comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment to the `fn` argument just makes that identifier to point to the anonymous function, `foo` in the outer scope is not affected.

When you pass an object as an argument, one can say "references are passed by value". The assignment just replaces the location where the `fn` identifier refers to.

That's how the [*evaluation strategy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) works in JavaScript.

Just before the assignment in the `fnChanger` functions, the two identifiers, the global `foo` and the `fn` argument, point to the same function object:

```
                ---------------------------------------------
    foo ----->  |function foo { sys.print('Un changed!'); } |
                ---------------------------------------------
                   ^
                   |
    fn -------------
```

After the assignment, `fn` will simply point to the new function:

```
                ---------------------------------------------
    foo ----->  | function foo { sys.print('Unchanged!'); } |
                ---------------------------------------------

                ---------------------------------------
    fn ------>  | function { sys.print('Changed!'); } |
                ---------------------------------------
```

How could you change it?

Well, assuming that `foo` is a function in the global scope, you could do something like this:

```
function fnChanger(obj, name) {
    obj[name] = function() { sys.print('Changed!'); };
}

function foo() {
    sys.print('Unchanged');
}

fnChanger(this, 'foo');
foo(); // Changed!
```

The above will work because in the `fnChanger` function, we require a *base object* and a *property name*, functions declared in the global execution context are bound as properties of the *Global object*, therefore we can re-assign its value in that way.

The line `fnChanger(this, 'foo');` should be executed also in the Global scope, it will pass the `this` value (which refers to the Global object in this scope) and a property name, allowing you to make an assignment to the `GlobalObject.foo` identifier.

If that code were inside a function, there is no way we can get a *base object*, because in this "Function Code Execution Context", function declarations (variable declarations and function formal parameters also) are bound as properties of a *non-accessible object*, called the Variable Object (a chain of these Variable Objects, forms the Scope Chain), and if it were the case, the only workaround would be to use `eval`.

More info:

- [ECMA-262-3 in detail. Chapter 8. Evaluation strategy.](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/)

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to suspect that's what is happening. Thanks for the clarification, and the link - I never knew exactly what to call that or how it worked. How can I get around this?

Comment: Ok, I like that approach. Not as messy as I was thinking of doing: passing an object containing the function to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

As @CMS pointed out you cannot assign it within the function due to the scope. However you could reassign it like this:

```
var fnChanger = function() {
  return function() {
      alert('changed!');
  }
}

var foo = function() {
  alert('Unchanged');
}

foo = fnChanger();
foo();
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/JmNLE/)

Comment: Yeah, thought about that. I'm hesitant to do it by return in the real code, though. On one hand, it's cleaner, but on the other, it doesn't quite match up with what the function actually does.

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant way around it

```
function fnChanger(fn_holder) {
    fn_holder["fn"] = function() { console.log('Changed!'); }
}
function foo() {
    console.log('Unchanged');
}

const foo_holder = {fn: foo}
fnChanger(foo_holder);

foo_holder["fn"]();  // Changed!
```

Short explanation:

1. Pass a higher level reference `foo_holder` to `fnChange` like a hash (or an array).
2. Reassign your element in side the hash `foo_holder["fn"]` to a new value. This will change where the inner reference is pointing instead of creating a new reference.
3. Then you're good to have fun with your updated function.

Answer (score 0):

**In Javascript, functions are first class objects that can be treated just as another variable**. But for the function to return its result, it has to be first invoked.

When you are invoking the fnChanger(foo), the fn variable actually gets overridden with foo().

But you are not getting the result because that function was never invoked. Try returning it and invoking as given below and you will the required answer.

```js
function fnChanger(fn) {
  fn = function() {
    console.log('Changed!');
  }
  return fn;
}

function foo() {
  console.log('Unchanged');
}

fnChanger(foo)();
foo();
```