# Reassigning javascript function in an attached js file

Tags: javascript, function, redirect

I have an HTML page with multiple attached js files that include functions that are used on that page.

For functions that are included on the base HTML page they are successfully re-assigned. FunctionA = FunctionB.

The problem comes when I try to reassign a function that is part of one of the attached js files. The normal reassignment doesn't work. Say FunctionC is on attached js file more functions.js .

I try FunctionC = FunctionD. FunctionC runs as it would normally - WITHOUT the reassignment to FunctionD. I know the reassignment to FunctionD 'should' occur before the FunctionC runs because it fires when I check with console.log.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing your reassignment *after* attached file `function.js`?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019849/javascript-re-assigning-a-function-with-another-function

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your reassignments *after* included file.

For example (*Disclamer: don't do this in real projects - this is for demo purposes only*) the code below includes jQuery library, but then overwrites jQuery function with a custom one:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery = function(s) {
        alert(s);
    }
</script>    

<script>
    jQuery('aaa');
</script>
```

when this runs it produces alert ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Bj9/1)), but if you reverse the order of first two script tags - original "attached" jQuery function will take over.